# How to use SharedPreferences to store form data in an Android app that uses Kotlin, Compose and Navigator?

Tags: kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am quite new to Android Studio, and for a study project, I am creating an app that uses Kotlin, Compose and Navigator. I want to store data from a form as key-value pairs in SharedPreferences, but although I have found an [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-session-management-using-jetpack-compose/) how to do it in Compose, this was not using navigator, and I haven’t been able to figure out where to initialize the variables with the navigator structure, can someone help me with that?

In the example, these variables are initiated at the start of MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    var PREFS_KEY = "prefs"
    var EMAIL_KEY = "email"
    var PWD_KEY = "pwd"
    var e = ""
    var p = ""
```

and then within setContent, shared preferences is initialized:

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
              sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

In my case with the navigator structure, I have tried placing the variables either in the MainActivity file, as well as within the navigator fragment where I want to store the values. If I place it in the MainActivity, the sharedPreference variable is not known in the navigator fragment, and when I place it in the main function of the navigator fragment, the line:
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
gives me the error: Unresolved reference: getSharedPreferences
(I have included import android.content.SharedPreferences in both files)

Comment: Since you are a beginner, I suıggest you to use dataStore rather than sharedPref as dataStore provides concurrency support and security. Look for Google DataStore and try to implement your project with that rather than dealing with issues related to SharedPreferences.

Comment: Thank you @Subfly , I had also discovered that in the meantime, and have started to implement it. Still have some issues there, but I guess those should be asked separately. I have used this site extensively to search answers since over a year now, but this is the first time I posted a question. I am not sure what to do with this question now that I use dataStore instead, should I remove it? I am still interested to learn how it should be done with SharedPreferences too...

Comment: I believe, leave the question as it is. Maybe someone with the same situation comes to that question and reads the comments and maybe gets an insight.